# Когда сортирyю сайт по рейтингy, то url остаётся таким же, из-за чего не полyчается спарсить по рейтингy. Что в таком слyчае делать?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Парсинг на python, bs4, requests. Когда сортирyю сайт по рейтингy, то url остаётся таким же, из-за чего не полyчается спарсить по рейтингy. Тоесть т.к url не меняется, то парсится без сортировки. Что делать чтобы парсило?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse():
    url = 'https://tropki.ru/rossiya/dagestan/gde-ostanovitsa'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 YaBrowser/20.6.1.151 Yowser/2.5 Yptp/1.23 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_='info-wrapper')
    items2 = soup.findAll('div', class_='reviews-column')

    all_rate = []
    all_names = []
    all_links = []
    all_money = []

    for item in items:
        name = item.find('a').get('title')
        link = 'https://tropki.ru' + item.find('a').get('href')

        all_names.append(name)
        all_links.append(link)

    for item in items2:
        kol = item.find('div', class_='rating-txt').get_text(strip=True)
        if kol == 'Прекрасно':
            price = item.find('div', class_='rating tooltip rating-excellent').get('title')
        elif kol == 'Отлично':
            price = item.find('div', class_='rating tooltip rating-verygood').get('title')

        price = price.replace('<br>', ' ')
        all_rate.append(price[:-12])

    for i in all_links:
        response = requests.get(i, headers=headers, verify=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        items3 = soup.findAll('div', class_='price-wrapper2')
        for z in items3:
            try:
                price = z.find('div', class_='price-wrapper').get_text(strip=True)
                all_money.append(price)
            except:
                all_money.append('-')

    all = []
    num = len(all_money)
    for i in range(num):
        all.append((all_names[i], all_rate[i], all_money[i], all_links[i]))

    all = sorted(all, key=lambda x: -float(x[1][8:12]))

    for i in all:
        print(f'Название:{i[0]}\n'
              f'Рейтинг:{i[1]}\n'
              f'Стоимость:{i[2]}\n'
              f'Ссылка:{i[3]}\n'
              )


parse()
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Привёл, сделал правкy.

Comment: Сортировка скорее всего с помощью аякса происходит

Comment: Тоесть это сделать невозможно?

Comment: Так вы добавьте в all пустые элементы вместо all_money[i], потом отсортируйте по рейтингу и после этого уже по сортированному и парсьте. В этом же суть или в чём?

Answer (score 0):

С минимальной переделкой вашего кода, если я правильно понял задачу:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse():
    url = 'https://tropki.ru/rossiya/dagestan/gde-ostanovitsa'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 YaBrowser/20.6.1.151 Yowser/2.5 Yptp/1.23 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_='info-wrapper')
    items2 = soup.findAll('div', class_='reviews-column')

    all_rate = []
    all_names = []
    all_links = []
    all_money = []

    for item in items:
        name = item.find('a').get('title')
        link = 'https://tropki.ru' + item.find('a').get('href')

        all_names.append(name)
        all_links.append(link)

    for item in items2:
        kol = item.find('div', class_='rating-txt').get_text(strip=True)
        if kol == 'Прекрасно':
            price = item.find('div', class_='rating tooltip rating-excellent').get('title')
        elif kol == 'Отлично':
            price = item.find('div', class_='rating tooltip rating-verygood').get('title')

        price = price.replace('<br>', ' ')
        all_rate.append(price[:-12])

    all = []
    num = len(all_links)
    for i in range(num):
        all.append([all_names[i], all_rate[i], 0, all_links[i]])

    all = sorted(all, key=lambda x: -float(x[1][8:12]))

    for a in all:
        print('парсим рейтинг', a[1])
        response = requests.get(a[3], headers=headers, verify=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        items3 = soup.findAll('div', class_='price-wrapper2')
        for z in items3:
            try:
                price = z.find('div', class_='price-wrapper').get_text(strip=True)
                a[2] = price
            except:
                a[2] = '-'

    all = sorted(all, key=lambda x: -float(x[1][8:12]))

    for i in all:
        print(f'Название:{i[0]}\n'
              f'Рейтинг:{i[1]}\n'
              f'Стоимость:{i[2]}\n'
              f'Ссылка:{i[3]}\n'
              )


parse()
```

Конечно, тут бы лучше отдельный класс сделать с инкапсуляцией названия, рейтинга и т.д., но и так работает, хоть код и не красивый.

```
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 9.4 из 10 на основе 201 отзыва
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 9.4 из 10 по отзывам
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 9.0 из 10 на основе 68 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 9.0 из 10 на основе 164 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 9.0 из 10 на основе 199 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.8 из 10 по отзывам
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.8 из 10 на основе 22 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.8 из 10 по отзывам
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.8 из 10 на основе 395 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.7 из 10 на основе 70 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.7 из 10 на основе 270 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.6 из 10 на основе 72 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.5 из 10 на основе 83 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.4 из 10 на основе 379 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.4 из 10 по отзывам
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.2 из 10 на основе 5 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.2 из 10 на основе 60 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.1 из 10 на основе 73 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.0 из 10 на основе 187 отзывов
парсим рейтинг Рейтинг 8.0 из 10 на основе 5 отзывов
```

Comment: Вы сортирyете с этой страницы, но на ней нет лyчших отелей. Тоесть есть отели с рейтингом 10

Comment: @Амин Значит, я не понял толком задачу. Наверное, вам тогда Selenium какой-нибудь нужен и имитировать нажатие кнопок для сортировки, и только после этого парсить что вышло.